# About Android Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have started my first android project and things all going well till here.

Things you should know

I successfully applied navigation drawer you can see it below image.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0oiN.jpg

My Requirement is like this below image ..

How can i accomplish like this.. when we click on men it slides and shows the other menus.

Image: http://s27.postimg.org/83nnp74ap/anim.gif

Answer (score 1):

we call that concept as navigation drawer with expendable list view

you can find the example here [Navigation drawer with expendable list view](http://mylearnandroid.blogspot.in/2014/06/android-custom-navigation-drawer-with.html)

Comment: Thats okay.. but how to make a slide when we click on men. like u seen in this image 

http://s27.postimg.org/83nnp74ap/anim.gif

Comment: That is with the help of animation.

Comment: Is there any example ? ... i have no idea how to do this.

Comment: it's simple just replace the list view with other list view when a particular list item is clicked you can find the code here [link](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer)

Answer (score 0):

Take `DrawerLayout` as the root view of your layout and add `"android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`. Just like my layout sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/home_drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="me.danielpan.youtubelike.HomeActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/home_coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:elevation="2dp"
        app:paddingEnd="0dp"
        app:paddingStart="0dp">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_appcompat"></include>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/home_tab_layout"
            style="@style/TabLayoutStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabContentStart="2dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
            app:tabMinWidth="24dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabPadding="1dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/tab_indicator_text"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/home_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:paddingEnd="0dp"
        app:paddingStart="0dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_toggle"
        app:borderWidth="1dp"
        app:elevation="3dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/home_coordinator_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="2dp"
        app:rippleColor="@color/swipe_refresh_color_scheme_green" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/home_navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start|left"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_view_header_layout"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation_view" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```